# How to get a appropriate columns with max(time) without using sub-query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table and the values:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------+-------+------------+
| id   | link  | time       |
+------+-------+------------+
|    1 | link1 | 2019-03-04 |
|    1 | link2 | 2019-03-05 |
|    1 | link3 | 2019-03-06 |
|    2 | link3 | 2019-03-07 |
|    2 | link4 | 2019-03-07 |
+------+-------+------------+
```

I want to get the columns *id* and *link* when time's value is max, 
I can using sub-query to finish it:

```
mysql> select B.id, B.link from test B, (select id, max(time) as time 
       from test group by id) A where A.time = B.time and A.id = B.id;
+------+-------+
| id   | link  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | link3 |
|    2 | link3 |
|    2 | link4 |
+------+-------+
```

I don't know how to finish it without using sub-query, any advice will be appreciated!

Another:

I want to get :

```
+------+-------+
| id   | link  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | link3 |
|    2 | link3 |
+------+-------+
```

OR

```
+------+-------+
| id   | link  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | link3 |
|    2 | link4 |
+------+-------+
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use corelated subquery

```
select a.* from test a
where (a.time,a.link) in(select max(time),max(link) from test b where a.id=b.id)
```

if your version is mysql 8.0+
then use `row_number()`

```
select * from (
select a.*,row_number()over(partition by a.id order by a.time desc) rn
 from test a
) b where b.rn=1
```

Comment: So sorry, I update my question, would you like to answer it! Thanks

Comment: @abelard2008 btw which version of mysql you used if mysql 8.0 then more easy solution is there

Comment: Thanks, I used both versions 5.7 and 8.0 in the different machines!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
  Select * from (select A.id,A.time,A.link, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by A.id order by A.time desc)As row_num from @tbl  A )AS AA Where AA.row_num =1
```

OR

```
select A.id,A.time,A.link from test  A
    order by A.time desc
    limit 1
```

Comment: ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY  clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.test.time' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: So sorry, I update my question, would you like to answer it! Thanks

Comment: which version of MySQL you tested it ? It did not work under 5.7

Comment: Please add some explanation to your queries such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit or top

limit (mysql) :

```
Select id,max(time),link  from test group by id,link  order by time desc limit 1
```

top (mssql):

```
 Select top 1 id,max(time),link  from test group by id,link  order by time desc
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? I don't think `TOP` exists in MySQL